# Assign specific dates based to an employee level dataset on weighted averages in excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, assign, weighted-average

I have a dataset in excel which shows headcount by employee level and which department each employee would fall under (sales, ops, or support). I would like to send a survey to each employee once every 26 weeks (2 times a year), but I would also like to keep sending surveys every week to ensure continuation of surveys to a certain amount of population split between sales, ops, and support departments based on their weight of the total population.

This way, I am sending surveys every week to a tiny bit of my overall headcount but only repeating people every 26 weeks.

Can anyone please help on how to solve this in excel with a formula?

From attached sample data, how can I split the headcount to send surverys for 26 weeks straight but to different population every week and not repeat? This different population should be split by % of department out of total headcount. Meaning if I have 10 people every week and % split is 40% sales, 30% operations, and 20% support, the survey should be sent to 4 sales, 3 operations, and 2 support people. Please note that the 10 people and the %s may vary every week because of new hires and resignations.

Thank you!

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lUWf.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do and show the formulas you have used?

Comment: And in addition to that, an example of data where you want the formula to work with.

Comment: Added a screenshot of an example and a detailed explanation. Need to populate column D. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the data sheet, ceate a helper column D, where you hand out the numbers to each employee, label it MOD. Use the formula for each employee, enter to cell D2:

```
=MOD(ROWS(A$2:A2)-1;$H$2)+1
```

That way each employee is assign a number from 1 to whatever is in the cell H2, e.g. 26. Then contact list all employees with 1 and you have the first batch and so you continue each week to get to employees with 26 in 26 weeks. This way all get the survey but just once.

Of course the share of the individual depts cannot be achieved each time, as there are less employees in some. If you wanted to keeps the shares, some employees of the smaller departments would get the survey more times.

If you want to get some randomness into the order, just mix the order of MOD numbers, e.g. start with 7, continue with 23 etc.

I hope I got the question right, I am not sure in some parts.